# Does allowing binfmt_misc significantly increase the attack surface for unprivileged users that already can launch - native - binaries?

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation

The Linux kernel lets me [register and execute additional binary](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html) formats as if they were regular executables.

I am thinking of this mostly as a *convenience* method, completing what specifying the interpreter via Shebang already partially accomplishes. Executed programs are as privileged and thus as dangerous as native binaries, *but not any bit beyond that*. Programs with slightly special format on disk; otherwise no special treatment. Is this assessment still correct on, say, a Ubuntu Linux desktop running all sorts of designed-for-single-user-systems setuid programs *and* permitting unprivileged user namespaces?

I am especially concerned about other *privileged* (setuid or talking to uid=0 daemons) programs such as `pkexec`, `systemctl`, `snap`, rtkit, `fusermount3` making assumptions about binaries they under very limited circumstances would grant some privileges to; assumptions that are not true for non-native binaries launched via the `binfmt_misc` mechanism. Ideally, I am looking for an answer pointing to previous flaws *proving* that this can indeed interact dangerously - or design choices that entire *rule out* this kernel capability to have security-sensitive side-effects other than the convenience of launching alien formats.

---

For what the features on their own mean for security, see these existing questions:

- [Can Windows malware harm a Linux computer when it's executed with Wine?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5119/can-windows-malware-harm-a-linux-computer-when-its-executed-with-wine/5122#5122)
- [user namespaces: do they increase security, or introduce new attack surface?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/267628/user-namespaces-do-they-increase-security-or-introduce-new-attack-surface)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the job of a binary interpreter is to parse the binary, set up memory regions, load the executable into memory, and facilitate execution etc. This process is transparent and completely handed off to the interpreter, whether in kernel or userspace (e.g. scripts with shebang). With binfmt_misc, creating e.g. an interpreter entry for PE files and running e.g. a PE file directly isn't much different than running  occurs at a lower level than what userspace programs concern themselves with. Additionally, running e.g. a Windows PE via `wine.exe` directly is not fundamentally different from creating a binfmt_misc entry to do the same, as far as how the interpreter functions.

> I am especially concerned about other privileged (setuid or talking to uid=0 daemons) programs such as pkexec, systemctl, snap, rtkit, fusermount3 making assumptions about binaries they under very limited circumstances would grant some privileges to; assumptions that are not true for non-native binaries launched via the binfmt_misc mechanism.

Without knowing what specific assumptions would apply here, it is difficult to evaluate this. Going back to the first point, those programs shouldn't really care what happens under the hood once they've called `execve`, as long as the binary starts executing.

However, it is worth noting with what privileges the interpreter runs with in various scenarios. The following snippet from the [Linux Kernel docs](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html) (same page you linked) seems relevant, emphasis mine:

> Currently, the behavior of binfmt_misc is to calculate the credentials and security token of the new process according to the interpreter. When [the C] flag is included, these attributes are calculated according to the binary. It also implies the O flag. This feature should be used with care as **the interpreter will run with root permissions when a setuid binary owned by root is run with binfmt_misc**.

With this option set, the interpreter is run with the setuid privileges of the executed binary, similar to how the dynamic loader would be executed when a setuid, dynamically-linked ELF is executed, though this behavior is not the case for shebang executables (which don't work with setuid in general) nor the default in binfmt_misc. If this option is enabled, it could be argued that this increases attack surface for privilege escalation, since exploitation of any vulnerabilities in the interpreter may result in privilege escalation.